# Flutter Text misaligned but textBaseline does not fix it

Tags: flutter

When trying to underline a mix of English and Japanese (or Chinese or Korean), the underline is not aligned, even when `textBaseline` is set to `ideographic`.

[image]

Code used to produce the above image:

```
  Text(
    "可愛い lovely",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 48,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
      textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
    ),
  ),
```

I thought the main purpose of `ideographic` text baseline is to address problems like this, but it made no visible differences. How should `textBaseline` be used then? And, is there any way to solve the underline misalignment issue in this case?

**Edit:**

Thanks to user @AnasMohammed pointing out the issue cannot be reproduced on DartPad, I then tried both Android and iOS. Seems like the problem only exists on Android. Sample results and "full code" available: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuRFO.jpg

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: @AnasMohammed You can paste the `Text` code snippet into any project to reproduce the issue. For example, you can start by creating a new Flutter project, and in the auto generated counter demo code, replace one of its Text widget with the code snippet in the question.

Comment: I already did that in DartPad, It shows text underline perfectly aligned in a straight line with the same code. so I asked for full code to check if there anything else which causes misaligned.

Comment: @AnasMohammed You are absolutely right, it aligns perfectly on the web version of DartPad. After further testing, it seems to be an issue only on Android, but not iOS. I have added more screenshots and "full code" to the question. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1032613 did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Set a fixed height say 1.3 in TextStyle may fix this problem. It is font specified problem, the default font family used on Android is not well designed for non-alphabet languages.

Comment: @Itk Thanks for the reply, although setting `height: 1.3` didn't fix it for me on android.